# Android Studio showing C Drive in project folders?

Tags: android-studio

I recently updated to 0.4.2 and got an ancient project up to snuff with the gradle tools and everything and now my C drive is showing up in my project files.

[image: C drive in project folder structure]

It does appear to be my actual C drive. It expands to show everything that explorer shows.

I'm not sure why this is happening and I'm not willing to risk deleting it for fear it might attempt to delete it from disk (as oppose to deleting it from the project).

My drives are set up a little abnormally. Android Studio is installed on my D drive, and my project is located on my E drive. My C is just the OS and My Documents.

Comment: Can you post your settings.gradle and build.gradle files?

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps :

1. Close Android Studio
2. Open C drive and delete the .iml file created, also delete if any .idea directory there.
3. Delete .iml file and content of .idea directory  inside your module.
4. Open Studio Again

Wait till Studio sync your project with gradle. If it says Unlinked Gradle project Project use import option in error message to import it again.